# Plotly choropleth shapes not showing

Tags: python, plotly, geojson, choropleth

I am trying to do a chloropleth map of Belgian municipalities based on a tutorial I found for US counties. I am using a geoJson file of municipalities which looks to have the correct shape. So far the output is just a default world map with basic country shapes, without any of the municipalities/polygons.

My code is:

```
fig = px.choropleth(df, geojson=municipalities, locations='nsi', color='value',
                           color_continuous_scale="Viridis",
                           featureidkey = 'nsi',
                           range_color=(0, 1),
                          )
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

The geojson['features'] data structure is:

```
{'type': 'Feature',
 'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon',
  'coordinates': [[[5.120302925755441, 51.04816305680891],
    [5.121797603837674, 51.047020715593455],
    [...]
    [5.120150449492362, 51.048366649842045],
    [5.120302925755441, 51.04816305680891]]]},
 'properties': {'nsi': '24020',
  'geo_point_2d': [51.002047103149735, 5.067897449665062],
  'name': 'Diest'},
 'id': '24020'}
```

df is a pandas dataframe with two columns: nsi (string) and value (float), corresponding to the feature id. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You might consider using Bokeh. Plotly does not seem to support mapping all that well in relative comparison -- its just unreasonably hard to do it. You could probably quickly port it over in just a few minutes by skimming this blog: https://thedatafrog.com/en/articles/choropleth-maps-python/

Comment: The part of the code that you want to check is the `featureidkey='propeties.nsi`, which is tied to the geojson file. Kindly refer to [this](https://plotly.com/python/choropleth-maps/).